# Vector push_back incredibly slow

Tags: c++, performance, vector

So I'm in the process of converting Java code that I wrote into C++ code for performance reasons as well as the intention of using CUDA to parallelize some of the stuff down the road. However, the first thing I wanted to do was a straight conversion and just have it running in C++ with the same code as was in java.

The issue I'm running into is that the loop down below is literally taking minutes to finish in C++ while it took barely any time at all in Java. The only difference being that I am using a vector in C++ and an `ArrayList` in Java.

I am also reserving the proper size for the neighbors vector when I initially create the cells vector. The purpose of this code is to create a uniform grid of cells in a 3d cube and to store the neighbors of each cell inside of the cell itself for convenience later.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 in case that matters (for C++) and Eclipse for java.

I feel like I am definitely missing something simple here as such a slowdown seems crazy, but when I comment out the `push_back`, the code executes basically instantly.

`w`, `h`, and `d` are all `20`. `cells` is a vector of `Cell` structs (seen below).

```
for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < d; k++) {
            for (int x = -1; x < 2; x++) {
                for (int y = -1; y < 2; y++) {
                    for (int z = -1; z < 2; z++) {
                        if (i + x >= 0 && i + x < w && j + y >= 0 && j + y < h && k + z >= 0 && k + z < d) {
                            cells[i][j][k].addNeighbor(cells[i + x][j + y][k + z]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Defined in a different file:

```
struct Cell {
    std::vector<Particle> particles;
    std::vector<Cell> neighbors;
    int b = 0;

    void addParticle(Particle &p) {
        particles.push_back(p);
    }

    void addNeighbor(Cell &c) {
        neighbors.push_back(c);
    }
};
```

Comment: `Cell`s inserted into a vector are *copied*, unlike in Java which merely stores a reference to the cells.  By doing this repeatedly, you end up with vectors of vectors of vectors of vectors ... see why it's so slow now?

Comment: Make sure you are running an optimized/release build.  Do not judge the speed of the STL containers using a debug build, and especially with Visual Studio.

Comment: As mentioned by @PaulMcKenzie could also give more details like the build settings i.e. release / debug build, running through debugger or command prompt, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++, standard containers such as `vector` store their elements by value, not by reference (as would be in Java).  This means your loops are creating cells that don't just *refer* to other cells, but *contain* them.  You end up creating a huge forest of nested of vectors that contain vectors, that themselves also contain vectors, and so on (up to about 20 levels in depth!).

What you probably want to do is to store a pointer to the adjacent cells instead:

```
struct Cell {
    ...

    std::vector<Cell*> neighbors;

    ...

    void addNeighbor(Cell &c) {
        neighbors.push_back(&c);
    }
};
```

This allows the cells to store weak references to each other.

Keep in mind that C++ doesn't have a garbage collector, nor does it do much safety checking, so it's entirely your responsibility to make sure that the cells are deallocated when they are no longer needed and that pointers are not dereferenced when the cells are gone.

Comment: if cells go out of scope, neighbors would also go out of scope. No way of accessing it.

Comment: This is what happens when I don't use a language for 8-9 months and forget basic things that I used to know. Thanks!

Comment: Can use `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` to deal with the scoping issue.

Comment: @Jagannath: that's not necessarily a problem if all the cells are allocated in the beginning and stored in some "master" array.

Comment: @Rufflewind: That's precisely what is going on. The cells and the program share the same lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

For Cells, the above answer would suffice. But for particle, would propose the following model:

```
void addParticle(Particle &p) {
        particles.push_back(p);
    }
```

The above code creates lot of Particle objects in the memory and does lot data copying. The following model would save memory allocations and copying:

```
struct Cell {
    std::vector<Particle> particles;
    Particle& getNextParticleRefForUpdate()
    {
        particles.push_back(Particle());
        return particles.at(particles.size() - 1);
    }
    ...
 };
```

The particle class would expose set function:

```
struct Particle
{
    int a;
    int b;

    void set(int& aval, int& bval)
    {
        a = aval;
        b = bval;
    }
    ...
};
```

While setting particle objects of a Cell object, the function would do the following:

```
Cell cell_val;
int aval = 5
int bval = 10;
Particle& par_val = cell_val.getNextParticleRefForUpdate();
par_val.set(aval, bval);
```